# Attaching data (body) to $http.delete event in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I have the following method in my Vue.JS component:

```
removeItems (itemsArray) {
    this.$http.delete(this.apiUrl, {items : itemsArray})
    .then((response) => {
       this.msg = response.msg;
    });
}
```

In vue-resource 0.8.0 everything worked fine. After upgrading to 1.0.3 it doesn't. I found in release notes that they deleted `body` from GET request, which makes sense, but why did the DELETE request stop working?
If they disabled specifying `body` explicitly in the DELETE request, how do I add it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a solution. Simply add `{body:data}` to the request:

```
removeItems (itemsArray) {
  this.$http.delete(this.apiUrl, {body: {items : itemsArray}})
  .then((response) => {
    this.msg = response.msg;
  });
}
```